# Выбор изображения из галереи

Tags: android, java, изображения

Есть **ImageView** , при нажатии на который открывается галерея для выбора фотографии.
При получении фотографии я устанавливаю это фото в **ImageView**. Если запустить это еще раз, то вылетает с ошибкой:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
image.setImageResource(0);
Uri photoUri = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
try
{
    Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
}
catch(
Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Stacktrace**:

> 0java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 1at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method) 2at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
>   3at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:308)
>   4at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:333)
>   5at
>   ru.qbit.adressbook.SettingsActivity.onActivityResult(SettingsActivity.java:337)
>   6at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
>   7at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
>   8at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
>   9at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
>   10at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
>   11at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 12at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 13at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 14at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 15at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 16at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>   17at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554) 18at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Мсье, вы считаете, что здесь форум экстрасенсов? Спешу вас огорчить, здесь форум программистов. Извольте предоставить более подробную информацию об ошибке, с которой вылетает приложение. Стектрейс подойдёт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.icon );
          image.setImageResource(0);
          Uri photoUri = data.getData();
          String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
          Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri,filePathColumn, null, null, null );
          cursor.moveToFirst();
          int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0] );
          String filePath = cursor.getString( columnIndex );
          cursor.close();
          try
          {
      Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath );
      Bitmap bitmapsimplesize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, bMap.getWidth() / size, bMap.getHeight() / size, true);
      bMap.recycle();
      image.setImageBitmap(bitmapsimplesize);
          }
          catch ( Exception e )
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
```